# Test mongodb map, reduce function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, testing, mapreduce

When I use mongoid mapreduce in rails, I pass the map and reduce function by string. for example

```
def group
  Order.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, :out => 'output_collection')
end

def map
  "function() 
   {
      var key = {game_id: this.game_id, year: this.date.getFullYear()};
      emit(key, {count: 1, score: this.score}); 
   }"
end

def reduce
  "function() 
   {
     var result = {sum: 0, total_score: 0, average: 0};
     values.forEach(function(value)
     {
       result.sum += value.count;
       result.total_score += value.score;
     });
   }"
end
```

Is it possible to test the map and reduce function in rails.
It is a simple example. But my project's function is more complicate, and I feel it is hard to maintainable.

Thanks for your help for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

For a test of a function that takes place in the database, your testing methodology is:

1. Create a base set of data
2. Run the function
3. Compare the results to your expected

So, in this case, you'll want to make sure the sum/average/total_score match what you expect.

Comment: Ya, that is what I do right now, I could just test the "group" method in this example. But writing javascript in this situation for map and reduce function, I think it is hard to read and maintain. Ya, I could give a bunch of comments for the map and reduce function, but I want to know is any solution could test map and reduce function